# Is it possible to change the default persistence model away from session persistence in Spring.Net?

Tags: persistence, spring.net

In Chapter 22 of the Spring.Net documentation (see 22.7.3. Customizing model persistence) at 
http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/web.html, they discuss changing the model for persisting data.

I don't use this functionality, so I have a custom persister that basically performs a noop, but to set it as the default, I basically have to configure the ModelPersistenceMedium property on every object.  I do this through a base page so it's not too bad, but I'd rather be able to change the default across the whole application so I don't have to worry about it.  Is there a way to do this without patching the source code for Spring?